# diagrams package

Tags: packages

I went to the diagrams package for installing commutative diagrams.  I am used to installing packages by running a dtx file, and then a sty file pops out and when the sty file is in the same folder as the place where I have my tex file with my math in it, the tex file runs properly.

But on Paul Taylor's page he says, 'Unlike many other packages there is no “installation procedure” — you just put the macros themselves in your TEX macros directory'.

This does not mean anything to me.  How can I take what is on the page here http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/diagrams.sty and somehow use the diagrams package whether it is through installation or some other means?

Comment: If you place the .sty file in your working directory (where your tex file is), it should find it directly during the compilation.  Your "TeX macros directory" is will depend on which flavor of LaTeX you are using.  Are you using, for example, MikTeX or something else.

Comment: It basically means you'll have to place the sty in the same folder as your `.tex` file. How ever I'd advice you to use a more modern system for diagrams, for example `tikz-cd`. Also remember to read the comments at the top of `diagrams.sty` where the author explains his requirements on you to use the package.

Comment: The problem was that there was no sty file on his page, or a dtx file that I could run to get a sty file.  That is why I can't put the sty file in the same directory as my tex file.  I am using the diagrams package because I managed to install the package 2 years back, and I know how to use the package.

Comment: what is on the referenced page is the file itself.  download it using the name `diagrams.sty`.  if you put it into your working directory, you should be all set.  the "time bomb" is quite far in the future now -- december 2019 -- so you won't have to be concerned about a new version until then.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: I found the package on ctan and ran the ins file on texshop, and a sty file came out that I could use.